# Is there any way to get all the data from the database at once and store it locally and get it locally

Tags: database, performance, web, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am working on a MIS project which contains 100000 records. I created a page where I edit the records, usually I got all the records in kendo grid from the database on 'onload' event using the ajax call, after that I apply some filters to see some specific record/records, but my question is that...

Is there any way to get all the data from the database at once and store it locally so that when ever I apply filter(want to see some records) on the data. It doesn't request from database. It show data from locally stored data.

Comment: Yes, there is but it is not efficient that's why people don't use to do it.

Answer (score 2):

I do agree with @OnaBai.. its not efficient if you handle huge number of data. On the first load it will take huge amount of time. Anyway, you can set `serverPaging: false` to achieve that.

```
dataSource: {

        serverPaging: false,
        pageSize: 20

    }
```

And when you need to access the data you do as usual;

```
$("#YourGridName").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.data()
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course, you just define your datasource as usually (define transport). If the data hasn't been *fetched* yet, it will call the server.

If you want to make it stay locally and not go to the server again each time you filter or sort, you must explicitly say it:

```
// This DS will reach the server only for fetching... 
var fatDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
        read: {
            url: ActionUrls.MonitoringReport.Alerts                
        }
    },
    // Specify that we want the operations locally
    serverSorting: false,
    serverFiltering: false,
    serverAggregates: false,
    serverPaging: false,
    serverGrouping: false
};
```

You can do whatever you want with the data, and no trip to the server will be needed, well, unless you explicitly call the read() method.

Now concerning the performance, I agree that the idea of fetching an entire database table to the front end might be a performance penalty in some cases (IE raise your hand). But, I won't judge you, I don't know if you're in an intranet or if you're building the next Google.

I'll give you some tips (in order of relevance):

- Please enable paging in your grid. The browser will not die if you want to store a 10000 items array in memory. But IT WILL DIE if you try to render a 10000 rows table. As you've seen, paging will be done locally, so you don't have to worry about any further ajax requests.
- Please enable GZIP compression for your ajax response. You'll see around 80% reduction in the network size.
- Please put a cache before your database table is reached. Don't kill your database server.
- If the records number is very very high, maybe you should consider not doing it at all :)